# How to find value of non-public state variable

Tags: solidity, evm, ganache, state-variable, ganache-cli

I understand that public state variables automatically creates a getter function when deployed, its value can be accessed via the getter function.

However, if a state variable is not public, how can we access the value? I am doing this for experiment purpose. Since everything is on the blockchain, even if a state variable is not public, we should still be able to find its value in the contract storage right?

I am running my contracts on Ganache, I saw one of the RPC for ganache is `eth_getStorageAt()`, maybe somehow it can be accomplished here?

`eth_getStorageAt` seems to return very raw information, if we can access the non-public state variable values, how do we locate it in the storage?

Answer (score 1):

A contract with two `storage` variables, one `public` and one `private`.

```
pragma solidity 0.7.0;

contract Test {
    uint256 public a = 10;
    uint256 private b = 20;
}
```

Variable `a` is stored at slot `0` and can be accessed using

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt(
    "address of contract",
    0,
    (
        err,
        slot_content
    ) => console.log(err, slot_content)
)
```

Variable `b` is stored at slot `1` and can be accessed using

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt(
    "address of contract",
    1,
    (
        err,
        slot_content
    ) => console.log(err, slot_content)
)
```